# Html anchors not working correctly in IE9

Tags: html

I have this dirty html that is currently used in my company, the issue is that the hyperlinks or anchors work in IE8, but not in IE9 any reason why this is not working in IE9?. Basically its just clicking on the link and then it should focus on the id, like when i click on specialties I see the url changing like this

```
file:///C:/Users/TestUser/Desktop/test.html#c3
```

Now in IE8 when i do the click it correctly goes to that section #c3

Well this code does not work either in IE9

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="titleC"><a href="#c3">Specialty</a></p>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p id="#c3">Did it work?</p>
<p>Then your code is wrong</p>
</body>
```

Comment: The W3 validator says your document has 368 errors.

Comment: geez, can you please post the url so i can see that? please

Comment: but i guess the question is.. why does it work in IE9

Comment: @user710502 Because different browsers respond differently to errors. Repair the errors and then it will most likely behave the same in IE8 as in IE9.

Comment: updated the code, this code was generated by an application... it was just given to see if i could see the issue.. I updated it just now with the semicolons. Also, no need to downvote without giving me a chance to improve whatever i need to.. this is what forums are for no?

Comment: @user710502 http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Yeah its really messed up thank you for the link i will look into it

Comment: This is a cleaned up version of the code to try out (still 6 Errors, 3 warning(s) included!) -- http://jsfiddle.net/e3d4r/

Comment: I saw the # as something that cant be used.. how is it calling the <p> ? if the # is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thehash is the problem:

```
<p id="c3">Did it work?</p>
```

(without the hash) should work.

Maybe you should use

```
<a id="c3" name="c3">Did it work?</a>
```

for compatibility reasons.

Comment: thank you very much, i left the hash for the href="#c3" and changed the name from name="c3" to name="#3" and it worked

Answer (score 1):

All you attributes need to but surrounded by single or double quotation marks. For one on the many incorrect lines in the html

```
<P id=#titleQ class=style1>
```

Should be

```
<P id="#titleQ" class="style1">
```

Comment: And more important: The element `<SPAN class="style12">` after `<P id=#2 class="style7">` has no end element. -- Indent your code or use tag highlighting if you can't find your errors via validator.

Comment: where can i find a validator?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this meta tag, maybe it would fix it:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8">
```

Comment: This is an option to set the browser/document mode, if your design does not work with newer version of the browser. This is not an option to work with really invalid html though.

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same issue and from my experience, on IE9 the anchor tag `<a>` does not recognise id or name on other elements other than another `<a>` tag, so as a workaround, you probably want to add a dummy empty `<a>` tag link above the element you want to link to, like so:

```
<body>
    <p id="titleC"><a href="#c3">Specialty</a></p>
    ...
    <a id="c3" name="c3"></a>
    <p>Did it work?</p>
    <p>Then your code is wrong</p>
</body>
```